# Brieskorn 4-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

As continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942255/3-manifold-embedded-in-1-connected-4-manifold) consider subset

$N^4=\{Re(x^p+y^q+z^r)=0:x,y,z\in\mathbb C, |x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2=1\}$

in sphere $S^5$. It is 4-manifold in sphere which contains Brieskorn $\Sigma(p,q,r)$ as submanifold. Is it possible to calculate homology groups of N ? Is it homology 4-sphere ?